# Running Selenium RC and PHP with xampp (phpunit not recognized error)

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, phpunit, xampp, selenium-rc

I have followed all the steps on this post but when i run the pear mytest.php i get the error 
http://jodyt.com/2009/03/selenium-rc-and-php/#comments

```
phpunit is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I dont know what i might be doing wrong. please guys any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks you in advance.
D~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because windows is not able to recognize phpunit as a program because location of phpunit.exe is not added to **Path** [environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).

just add **;C:/xampp/php** at the end of the value of Path environment variable(note semicolon is important, Also I'm assuming your xampp is in C:/)

Hope this helps.